Why is echo "string" | md5 AND md5 -s "string", give different has values?
echo 'string' | md5 and md5 <<< 'string' both give the result:
b80fa55b1234f1935cea559d9efbc39a
Whereas md5 -s 'string' gives the result: b45cffe084dd3d20d928bee85e7b0f21
Why is this so?
Edit: This is on macOS

run echo 'string' | hexdump -C and printf "string" | hexdump -C and see the difference
